# Why can I only send 100 emails from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, email, google-workspace-for-business, google-api

Please, can somebody explain why I can only send 100 emails a day even though I am a G-suite upgraded user that's already passed the free trial account? Even if I was still on a free trial account, that limit should be 500.

Will reward anyone that can answer this as I have been stuck for some time now and no one seems to know and Google support doesn't help with API.

Answer (score 1):

As of 30th January 2014, the limit was reduced to **100** emails per day (the last update from August 2018 didn't bring any changes to that)

[image: 0]

- **[https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en&dark=1)**

---

The latest quotas can be checked at **[Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)**. Also, take notice to:

> Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or **several billing cycles** if they have fewer users.

[image: 0]

---

You are able to check directly for your remaining quota status with **[`getRemainingDailyQuota()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?csw=1#getRemainingDailyQuota())** command

Comment: Thank you for the response but doesn't that say number of recipients per email. My number of recipients per email is 1 not 100?

Comment: 1 email with 100 recipients is like 100 emails each with one recipient. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSJfW.png means that 50 people got one email from you so you sent 50 emails to 50 people

Comment: I'm not sure i quite understand. i sent 100 separate emails to different people. They was not in CC or Bcc. 

It would not make sense to be able to send 2000 emails day but only allowed 100 recipients. 2000/100=20 ... Who would want to send 20 emails a day to the same person?

Comment: But if this is the case, does that mean it's not possible to ever use Google for email campaigns with more than 100 emails/recipients?

Comment: you can send 2000 emails only directly from Gmail. 500 emails also from Gmail if you use delegate emails for example. when sending via google sheets you don't use Gmail but Gmail API so your limit is 100. for the campaign there are different solutions. for example, https://www.gmass.co/ which is able to bypass email limits from the pictures above